# play/pause icon on video video tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I want to display `<i class="fa fa-play fa-5x"></i>`before video is played and  `<i class="fa fa-pause fa-5x"></i>` when the video is paused.

```js
var video = document.getElementsByClassName('vid');
video.addEventListener('click', function() {
  video.play();
}, false);
```

```html
<video width="85%" height="auto" class="vid" poster="image/video1.jpg" onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause();">
  <source src="video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 2):

- Remember to load the **[Font Awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)** stylesheet.
- Use **[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** to switch the button's classes `fa-play` and `fa-pause`.
- Avoid using inline event handlers use **[`addEventListener`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp)**
- I intentionally separated the button from the video tag because it's huge and would obscure the video.

```js
var playPause = document.getElementById('btn');
var vid = document.querySelector('.vid');

playPause.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!vid.paused) {
        vid.pause();
      } else {
        vid.play();
      }
      playPause.classList.toggle('fa-play');
      playPause.classList.toggle('fa-pause');
      return false;
    }, false);
```

```css
#btn {
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<video width="85%" height="auto" class="vid" poster="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs34s3.png">
  <source src="https://glpjt.s3.amazonaws.com/so/av/vs34s3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<i id="btn" class="fa fa-play fa-5x"></i>
```